# \date doesn't show date

Tags: date

My LaTeX code is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[lined, linesnumbered, ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

% \usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage[hyperref=true,backend=bibtex8,sorting=none,backref=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase{My Report}}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape MY NAME}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  % page number in the center at the footer

% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % remove the horizotal line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}  % remove the footer line


% \parindent 0ex % no need for indent
% \setlength{\parindent}{4em}  % indentation of paragraph

% \setlength{\parskip}{1em} % length between paragraphs
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % line spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
\huge{\textbf{My Group}} \\
% \Large{\textbf{My Report}} \\
\vfill
\line(1, 0){430}\\[1mm]
\Large{\textbf{TITLE 1}} \\[3mm]
\Large{\textbf{TITLE 2}}\\[1mm]
\line(1, 0){430}
\vfill

My NAME \\
ME@ME.com \\
http://ME.COM \\
%\today
\date{August 4, 2018}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}  % set page number 1

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\section{My Section}

HELLO HERE is My Section........

\end{document}
```

using `\today` is can show the date on the page, however, using `\date{August 4, 2018}` it doesn't show the date on the page. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\date{}` is to specify the date - either by a free text, such as your  `August 4, 2018` or by using the current day `\date{\today}`. This stores the date for later use.

To insert it in your document, you could use

```
\makeatletter
\@date
\makeatother
```

or just write it in plain text, as you do for all your other elements like title, author etc.

---

some other comments about your code:

- please don't load the same package more than once
- commands like `\huge` are switches and don't take arguments

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[lined, linesnumbered, ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

% \usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage[hyperref=true,backend=bibtex8,sorting=none,backref=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape \MakeUppercase{My Report}}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape MY NAME}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  % page number in the center at the footer

% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % remove the horizotal line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}  % remove the footer line

\date{August 4, 2018}

% \parindent 0ex % no need for indent
% \setlength{\parindent}{4em}  % indentation of paragraph

% \setlength{\parskip}{1em} % length between paragraphs
% \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % line spacing

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}
{\huge\textbf{My Group}} \\
% \Large{\textbf{My Report}} \\
\vfill
\line(1, 0){430}\\[1mm]
{\Large \textbf{TITLE 1}} \\[3mm]
{\Large\textbf{TITLE 2}}\\[1mm]
\line(1, 0){430}
\vfill

My NAME \\
ME@ME.com \\
http://ME.COM \\
%\today
\makeatletter
\@date
\makeatother


\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}  % set page number 1

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\section{My Section}

HELLO HERE is My Section........

\end{document}
```