# How to add date on the title page while using jcappub.sty?

Tags: pdftex

I am using [jcappub.sty](https://jcap.sissa.it/jcap/help/JCAP_TeXclass.jsp). For instance -

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{jcappub} 
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\date{\today}
\section{Section:1}
.
.
\end{document}
```

I am trying to add the date on the title page. I followed the suggestion by [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444710/149108)-

```
\makeatletter
\@date
\makeatother
```

But the date is going to be shown on the content-page. Is there any solution?

Comment: How are you using that package? Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/79060).

Comment: Can you make the example more complete, e.g. containing a `document` environment and generating (at least) the title-page output. Knowing how the title-page is generated is important.

Comment: By [JCAP-author-manual.pdf](https://jcap.sissa.it/jcap/help/JCAP/TeXclass/DOCS/JCAP-author-manual.pdf), `jcappub.sty` redefines `\maketitle` so that date is not shown. If you are using this package to submit to jcap, there is no need to change its title-page style.

Comment: Before submitting to JCAAP, I need to submit to our research group. And there I need to mention the date on the manuscript page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the discussion under question, one can add the date info to title-page by directly inputing date in `\author{...}`, or by patching `\maketitle`.

The following example patches `\maketitle` and add date info on title-page, directly under author.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{jcappub} 
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketitle}
  {\the\auth@toks\par}
  {\the\auth@toks\par\textmd{\@date}\par}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section:1}
.
.
\end{document}
```

[image: add date info to title-page, with jcappub.sty loaded]